# android - best way to shared the action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I aim to shared the action bar in all activities. So I create a based class call "MyActionBarActivity" as follows"

```
public class MyActionBarActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static int TL = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "I am settings", TL).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

and other activities inherit from this class to share the action bar.

```
public class Activity1 extends MyActionBarActivity {

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);

}}
```

public class Activity2 extends MyActionBarActivity {

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

}}
```

Is this a good way to implement the action bar?

Comment: fragments with view flipper is the best option in my head!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is a fine way to apply the common action bars in more than one activity.

But inflating in separate activities also won't make much difference.

You can use either ways.